# How to calculated and save the value into database

Tags: php

I'm try to calculated the value but some of it doesn't function. And it also doesn't insert into database. Please somebody help me. I'm doing my final year project right now.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$no1=$_POST[peruntukan_diluluskan];
$no2=$_POST[jumlah_perbelanjaan];
$tolak6=$_POST[baki];

$tolak6=($no1-$no2);


$query=" INSERT INTO form (baki)
VALUES ('$tolak6')"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);

 ?>

<table width="800" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><strong>1</strong></td>
            <td width="170"><span class="gh"><strong>Peruntukan diluluskan (Approved budget)</strong></span><strong> </strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td width="472"><?php echo $record["peruntukan_diluluskan"]; ?><input name="peruntukan_diluluskan" type="hidden" id="peruntukan_diluluskan" readonly ="readonly" value="<?php echo $record["peruntukan_diluluskan"]; ?>" size="50" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="30"><strong>2</strong></td>
            <td width="170"><span class="hb"><span class="hb"><strong>Jumlah Perbelanjaan (Amount Spent) </strong></span></span><strong></strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td width="472"><?php echo $record["jumlah_perbelanjaan"]; ?><input name="jumlah_perbelanjaan"type="hidden" id="jumlah_perbelanjaan" readonly ="readonly"  value="<?php echo $record["jumlah_perbelanjaan"]; ?>" size="30" /></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td width="30"><strong>3</strong></td>
            <td width="170"><span class="hb"><span class="hb"><strong>Baki (Balance) </strong></span></span><strong></strong></td>
            <td width="10">:</td>
            <td width="472"><?php  echo $tolak6;
 ?><input type="hidden" name="baki" id="baki" value="<?php  echo $tolak6;
 ?>" size="50" /></td>
          </tr>
```

Comment: The inputs from forms are always strings so you might be trying to write a string value to the database field that has a double of int data type. You need to convert the inputs with $tolak6 = floatval($no1) - floatval($no2);

Answer (score 0):

Write correct MySql insert format

```
INSERT INTO table_name ( field1, field2,...fieldN ) VALUES ( value1, value2,...valueN );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like you're not connected to a database.

You need to use some MySQL connections to establish which server the DB lives on, and which DB you want to connect to.

`$record` is never populated, either.

You'll probably want to throw the $_POST variables inside quotes, too:

```
$no1=$_POST['peruntukan_diluluskan'];
$no2=$_POST['jumlah_perbelanjaan'];
$tolak6=$_POST['baki'];  //this is immediately overwritten.. 
$tolak6=($no1-$no2);
```

P.S. You should do a better job of paramaterizing your queries. (:

Answer (score 0):

missing db connection

add like this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$mysql_database = "testdb"; //your database name



$conn = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password, $mysql_database);

 // $conn  is db connection variable 

if (!$conn) 
{

    die("Connection failed");
    }
     ?>
```

and you have to use POST value like

```
     $no1=$_POST['peruntukan_diluluskan'];
      $no2=$_POST['jumlah_perbelanjaan'];
      $tolak6=$_POST['baki']; //here you have to use different variable 

     $tolak6=($no1-$no2); //here you overwriting the same variable
```

and missing connection variable

```
     $query=" INSERT INTO form (baki)
    VALUES ('$tolak6')"; 
    $result=mysql_query($conn,$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below statement.

```
$con=mysql_connect("hostname", "username", "password") or die(mysq_error());
mysql_select_db("database_name", $con);
$query=" INSERT INTO form (baki)
VALUES ('$tolak6')"; 
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

Now a days php support **mysqli** driver.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u to first check the form element. Use post method inside form `<form method="post" action="your php file name">`Then create a connection with your local host and use that connection variable to make transaction between database.
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","usename","password","databasename");`

Then create query for insert and make transaction

```
`$q = "insert into tablename(field1,field2,...,fieldn) values (val1,val2,...valn)";
```

Mysqli_query($q);`

Try it. Happy coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

$no1=$_POST['peruntukan_diluluskan'];
$no2=$_POST['jumlah_perbelanjaan'];
$tolak6=$_POST['baki'];
$tolak6=($no1-$no2);

$con= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die( " Error"."Connection failed: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testdb") or die( " Error"."DB selection failed: ".mysql_error());
$query="INSERT INTO form (baki) VALUES ('$tolak6')";
$result=mysql_query($con,$query) or die(mysql_errno($con,$query));

?>

<table width="800" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td width="30"><strong>1</strong></td>
        <td width="170"><span class="gh"><strong>Peruntukan diluluskan (Approved budget)</strong></span><strong> </strong></td>
        <td width="10">:</td>
        <td width="472"><?php echo $record["peruntukan_diluluskan"]; ?><input name="peruntukan_diluluskan" type="hidden" id="peruntukan_diluluskan" readonly ="readonly" value="<?php echo $record["peruntukan_diluluskan"]; ?>" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30"><strong>2</strong></td>
        <td width="170"><span class="hb"><span class="hb"><strong>Jumlah Perbelanjaan (Amount Spent) </strong></span></span><strong></strong></td>
        <td width="10">:</td>
        <td width="472"><?php echo $record["jumlah_perbelanjaan"]; ?><input name="jumlah_perbelanjaan"type="hidden" id="jumlah_perbelanjaan" readonly ="readonly"  value="<?php echo $record["jumlah_perbelanjaan"]; ?>" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="30"><strong>3</strong></td>
        <td width="170"><span class="hb"><span class="hb"><strong>Baki (Balance) </strong></span></span><strong></strong></td>
        <td width="10">:</td>
        <td width="472"><?php  echo $tolak6;
            ?><input type="hidden" name="baki" id="baki" value="<?php  echo $tolak6;
            ?>" size="50" /></td>
    </tr>
```